# What's the cheapest 200 Medium Unit Container Cargo ship?

Tags: x3-terran-conflict

I'm looking for a cheap ship with about 200 units of space and can handle medium cargo containers.

What's the cheapest ship in this range, and who sells it?

Comment: Just reminding me that I *have* to play to this game lying on my HDD for ages. Bought it just because I buy all Elite clone since then... :) and this one seems quite good!

Comment: I was skeptical at first, but X3 terran conflict is insanely addictive.

Comment: Is there a demo of the game somewhere? I'm having a hard time getting an impression of how it plays.

Comment: @Raven From what I know, only a rolling demo playing also the role of benchmark: http://www.egosoft.com/download/x3tc/demos_en.php

Comment: @Raven - It's something of a sandbox game that comes from a long line of space trading games, starting back with Elite and TradeWars (from BBSes (pre-internet you noobs!)).   The genre dried up during the 2000s, but X3 was the last in that style of game to be created.  Though a sequel has just been announced.

Comment: Of course, eve online is the multiplayer equivalent and it's been around for a while now.

Answer (score 2):

**Paranid Demeter or Demeter Tanker**

price: 172,178

cargo: 2800 , upgrdable to 3800, type XL

Demeter can be purchased from: Third Redemption, Cardinal's Domain or Heaven's Assertion

Demeter Tanker can be purchased from: Paranid Prime, Third Redemption, Duke's Citadel or Heaven's Assertion

**option #2**: Capture Pirate Ships

Comment: +1 for capturing pirate ships.  Unless you are trying to curry Duke's favor to do his missions for the rare medusa prototype, there's really no reason why you shouldn't attack his unarmed transports :)

Answer (score 0):

The cheapest 200 unit medium cargo ship is the [Mako](http://eng.x3tc.ru/x3_tc_ships/x3-ship.php?c=MzM1NTEyMzU)

The Mako costs about 373070 and can carry a maximum of 208 Medium cargo units when fully upgraded.

It's sold by the Boron.